# How to fetch the records based on the no of occurences of a value in certain field in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to fetch the records with the field named ppno by occurances. ie.

```
(GIVE ME RECORDS WHERE PPNO repeating same 5 times)
```

like this

```
Name   PPNO
John   TNi89873 
Smith  TNi89873 
Mark   TNi89873 
Joe    TNi89873 
Cane   TNi89873
Mary   OCSV
Mark   OCSV
Don    OCSV
Crook  OCSV
Mike   OCSV
```

Comment: noway... hope u understood question wrong

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
select * from tbl where ppno in
    (select ppno from tbl group by ppno having count(ppno) > 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      T1.Name,
            T1.PPNO
FROM        table AS T1
WHERE       T1.PPNO IN (SELECT     T2.PPNO
                        FROM       Table AS T2
                        WHERE      T2.PPNO = T1.PPNO
                        HAVING     COUNT(T2.PPNO) = 5)
ORDER BY    T1.PPNO,
            T1.Name
```

Something like this ( untested )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, PPNO FROM Table WHERE PPNO IN
(SELECT PPNO FROM Table GROUP BY PPNO HAVING Count(PPNO)=5)
```